# visual studio installer нет подключения к интернету

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-11

Мне нужно установить VS buildtools, делаю это через установщик vs installer. Получаю ошибку подключения к интернету. Такое ощущение, что эта утилитка пытается что-то скачать и не может подключиться к интернету.

Находил подобную [тему](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-visual-studio/4544d220-8887-4df2-8d43-56edca6747f1), там было 2 совета, первый - с работающим VPN попробовать установить, но он не работает. Второй совет касался изменения свойств сетевой карты, прописать там общедоступные DNS. Поковырялся, погуглил, не смог найти как это сделать. Буду рад любому совету, может кто знает как изменить свойства карты, тоже будет полезно, попробую, вдруг поможет

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в антивирусе, так же можете попробовать подключиться к другой сети. Еще как вариант сменить версию или обновиться.